# How to host an Apache based site alongside an IIS based site?

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, iis, windows

I've inherited a simple small business network which has a single SBS 2003 server running Exchange. It's currently set up so that the domain name `mail.company.com` maps to the server IP, so email can be accessed outside the network.

I don't want to mess with the SBS 2003 setup too much, however, I would like for them to be able to host `intranet.company.com` on the same IP, but mapped to a machine running their Apache-based intranet site so that 'road warriers' can access it too (it would basically become a public website).

We have a single static IP address, an all-in-one firewall/gateway/router and a single Windows SBS 2003 server with DNS and DHCP. The Apache machine is just a Windows 7 box on the network.

Assuming application-level security is as good as it will be for now, so that turning their intranet application into a website application has minimal risk for them, what should I be looking at to actually make it work? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the users do not need to access a web site on the SBS server, then this can be handled with port forwarding.  Set the router up to forward port 25 to mail.company.com and port 80 & 443 to the Windows 7 box.

If the users need to access a website on the SBS server then you could use Apache as a front-end and use mod_proxy to forward to the SBS server.  Something like this should help get you started.

```
 ProxyPass           /sbs  http://mail.company.com
 ProxyPassReverse    /sbs  http://mail.company.com
```

Comment: Thanks uSlackr, what would the equivalent be for IIS? The Windows Server is already configured to be the primary server, and the apache box is just a Windows 7 machine.